# Why won't my hot water tank heat in extremly cold weather?

Tags: water-tank

My hot water tank cannot heat up water in extremely cold weather, like -25°C. I called my plumber who replaced the hot water tank for me three years ago when this happened the same year he replaced it for me, he suggested me to turn up my temperature gauge on the tank. But it does not help. Usually I am not too worried because when the weather comes back, the hot water comes back, too. This has been happening once per year in the past three years.

However, it happened twice in recent two weeks, because the extreme cold hit us twice. This second time has been three days, and I expect it to last for another two/three days, looking at the weather forecast.

Why is the cold weather affecting the tank? The tank is in my basement, where is pretty warm - 18°C.

My tank uses natural gas, I believe.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Perhaps the hot water is going through pipes in a wall that is really cold and you are losing heat that way.   Pipe insulation may fix the problem if you can get to the pipes.

Comment: If you can't get to the existing pipes then run new ones.

Comment: Thanks for responding.The pipe on top left of the third picture, which I just uploaded, should be the hot water pipe - I think it was hot on normal days, but cold now. This pipe is for sure inside the house, though. Thus, I think the problem is the water is not heated up.

Comment: Is it possible that your gas service doesn't have enough capacity to run this water heater plus your furnace?

Comment: Does it indicate whether it is heating at the moment or not? (maybe the green light?) Does that indication ever go off? Is the pipe hot when it goes off? Is the chimney pipe hot/warm when it is supposed to work? Does it actually burn (is there flame)? Could something be frozen? Like incoming water or even the incoming gas pipe? How cold is the incoming water? How warm is the output hot water?

Comment: Think @jwh20  has the right idea.  Hot water tanks usually do not care what outside temperature is(unless they are outside also).  Would get a gas technician in to check furnace and tank and see if the tank is getting enough gas with the furnace on.  Furnaces use more gas the colder it gets outside.  About the only thing that makes sense in your case.

Comment: When the heater is not working, you should go outside to where the vent pipes terminate (probably a wall near the water heater, or sometimes they go through the roof). Check if there is any ice built up in either of the pipes. If there is, that could be your problem.

Comment: Turn on a hot water valve somewhere and then check the temperature on the hot water pipe just above the tank. It should be very hot to the touch. If it is not, then the tank is not working right. If it is hot and the water coming out the tap in the house is not, then there is a problem with poor insulation of the pipe. Do you have a recirculation loop?

Comment: @JimStewart I did what you suggested, and it seems the problem is the tank itself. I turned on hot water in my kitchen, and the left copper pipe on the third picture gets warm to around 20~25 degrees celsius, the same as the hot water in the kitchen. As for a recirculation loop, I searched up online to understand it. I believe I have it - see the fourth picture I just uploaded - the right copper pipe must be it.

Comment: @PhilippNagel Thanks for the information. The vent pipe is fine. Recently I check it everyday.

Comment: @jwh20 and crip659 Gas capacity should be fine - in my house natural gas is used by the furnace, water heater, fireplace, and there is even an outlet for barbecue stove. I checked the fireplace a minute ago, and it looks normal to me.

Comment: @Lukas I believe the green light is the indicator. It blinks once a second usually. The pipe gets a littble warmer when I turned on hot water in my kitchen, as Jim Stewart suggested. As for the flame, I cannot tell. I knew I could see flame when I checked a tank very old (around 1980). But I don't think I can find a way to see the flame with my current tank. The incoming water feels probably 5 degrees celsius and the outcoming water feels 25 degrees.

Comment: There is a motor hidden behind the plastic on the top of the tank. It turns on and off by itself. The green light labeled `status` blinks. These things make me think there could be some autamatical control inside the tank, and the control works according to the temprature. Is it possible the problem is caused by some sensors used by the control? I have no experience about the hot water tank what so ever. I am just guessing with some degree of desperation...

Comment: What do you have for fresh air intake?  If both the tank and the heater are fighting for the fresh air, one could shut off.  I had issues with my boiler when I plugged the PVC pipe the internet came in because wasps were nesting in the basement, and it prevented the boiler from operating for more than a few seconds at a time because there was no other fresh air source.

Comment: @rtaft Fresh air intake is a puzzle for me. I have always been wondering where the fresh air comes in. Let me do some online search...

Comment: @sofname If you have basement windows, you could leave one open a crack, that should allow enough fresh air in to test to see if it's an air intake issue.

Comment: @rtaft Thanks you for solving my problem - fresh air intake was blocked with snow, and that is the problem. The outside of the intake looked clear/clean, but inside the intake pipe there was lots of snow blocking most of it. After cleared the snow out, the air motor has been making pleasure noise for a long time now - and the water is getting warmer and warmer. (I did not test by openning a window though - I think the air circulation is in a loop with one pipe in and one pipe out, separated set up for furnace and water tank.)

Comment: @rtaft Could you possibly put your answer about checking fresh air intake as a separate post? I would like to flag it as the answer so that other people can benefit from it.

Comment: @sofname posted.  I almost posted as an answer before but I saw the black pipe and thought it might have it's own air intake so I asked as a comment instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have adequate fresh air intake.  There is typically a sensor on gas boilers, water heaters, and furnaces that will shut off the flame if it detects low pressure from blowing the exhaust out.  If both the furnace and hot water tank are fighting over a limited air intake, it could cause one or both to not operate properly.  It could also be that the hot water tank's sensor is a bit more sensitive than the furnace to the lack of fresh air and shuts off while the other does not.  Also make sure the intake is not plugged.

Comment: A tip for the readers: the tricky part for me was I had to put my hand inside the intake pipe to find the snow/ice. Looking only the outside did not help as the outside was very clean

Comment: So does this arrangement have separate PVC pipes for intake (combustion) air and for combustion products (water vapor, CO2 + traces of noxious gasses*)? It looks like you have a very high quality installation. This appears to be a high efficiency "condensing" water heater which requires forced air  to expel the exhaust gas because the exhaust is not hot enough to draw exhaust out by convection. This is essential for high efficiency, but IIUC if you lose electric power the water heater will not heat water. Possibly these have a limp mode where they heat at a fraction of the normal rate.

Comment: Some tankless water heaters use concentric pipes for intake and exhaust. Do any "condensing" tank water heaters use concentric pipes for intake and exhaust?

Comment: @JimStewart Yes this syste has separate pipes for intake air and outcoming products. It does say high efficiency somewhere and I believe it has some exhausting moter/fan.

Answer (score 1):

Look inside your intake pipe. Mine was full of snow and won't let any air in. The exhaust pipe can blow itself out; the intake does not.

Answer (score 0):

This screams poor pipe insulation. I bought a new house many years ago and when we would have severe cold snaps that went well below freezing, I would have one of my bathroom taps freeze up. I learned that leaving the cabinet doors open helped some, but the line was too close to the wall and would still freeze in some extreme circumstances. It relied too heavily on the wall insulation and needed a direct insulation.

As a simple "start here" you might want to insulate the parts of the hot water line in your basement that are not copper (most code does not allow pipe insulation down the the tank itself). That would at least get you some thermal efficiency back for minimal cost and effort. Be sure to use closed-cell foam and not the cheaper stuff. You want as much R-value on that pipe as possible.

You could see about getting a thermal camera and try to trace where the pipes are losing too much heat (in extreme cold it should be easy to find on the outside of your house). If that location is accessible, you might be able to open a small section of the wall from the inside, add some insulation, and close it back up with minimal effort.

Failing that, you might be able to get a small point-of-use tank into places where the water never gets warm for the winter months (not cheap, but it would work)

Comment: Turn on a hot water valve somewhere and then check the temperature on the hot water pipe just above the tank. It should be very hot to the touch. If it is not, then the tank is not working right. If it is hot and the water coming out the tap in the house is not, then there is a problem with poor insulation of the pipe. Do you have a recirculation loop?

Comment: @JimStewart Might want to post this under the question

Comment: Thanks for the idea of insulation. However, from the test suggested by Jim Stewart, the problem should be the tank itself. I think I will add some insulation later, for different reason though - in the summer, I don't want the pipes heat up my house.